# Excel and XML parsing using Java

Tags: java, xml, excel

I have the code below which gets data from excel and converts in into a XML file using POI.
I'm stuck with 2 cases;
1) When it parses to XML file, the numeric values are in double type which should be Integer (i.e: 2859.0).
2) The last column is not parsed.
The Excel file contains the following columns:

NAME, DESCRIPTION, PRODUCER, UM, CATEGORY, START_ACTIVE_DATE,END_ACTIVE_DATE

It parses and saves to XML all the columns except the last one which is END_ACTIVE_DATE and shows numeric values as double. Any ideas?

Moreover, I think the problem might be with the cases when the data in the column is empty because as far as I see if there is no data for that particular cell it generates the tag of that cell but writes the value of the next cell...

```
    public void displayFromExcel (String xlsPath)
    {
        InputStream inputStream = null; 
        try
        {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream (xlsPath);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println ("File not found in the specified path.");
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

        POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = null;

        try {
            //Initializing the XML document
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = document.createElement("records");
            document.appendChild(rootElement);


            fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem (inputStream);
            HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook (fileSystem);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt (0); 
            Iterator<?> rows = sheet.rowIterator ();

            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
            while (rows.hasNext ()) 
            {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next(); 
                int rowNumber = row.getRowNum ();
                // display row number
                System.out.println ("Row No.: " + rowNumber);

                // get a row, iterate through cells.
                Iterator<?> cells = row.cellIterator (); 

                ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (cells.hasNext ())
                {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next ();
                    switch (cell.getCellType ())
                    {
                    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC :
                    {
                        // NUMERIC CELL TYPE
                        //System.out.println ("Numeric: " + cell.getNumericCellValue ());
                        rowData.add(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "");
                        break;
                    }
                    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING :
                    {
                        // STRING CELL TYPE
                        HSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell.getRichStringCellValue ();

                        //System.out.println ("String: " + richTextString.getString ());
                        rowData.add(richTextString.getString ());
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        // types other than String and Numeric.
                        System.out.println ("Type not supported.");
                        break;
                    }
                } // end switch
            } // end while
            data.add(rowData);
        } //end while

        int numOfData = data.size();

        for (int i = 1; i < numOfData; i++){
            Element dataElement = document.createElement("data");
            rootElement.appendChild(dataElement);

            int index = 0;
            for(String s: data.get(i)) {
                String headerString = data.get(0).get(index);
                Element headerElement = document.createElement(headerString);
                dataElement.appendChild(headerElement);
                headerElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
                index++;
            }
        }

        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();

        //Add indentation to output
        transformer.setOutputProperty
        (OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(
                "{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");

        // Define source
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("c:\\Users\\Temped\\Desktop\\dataXML.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("ParserConfigurationException " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("TransformerConfigurationException "+ e.getMessage());
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        System.out.println("TransformerException " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    ExcelXMLParser generateOutput = new ExcelXMLParser ();
    String xlsPath ="C:\\Users\\Temped\\Desktop\\dataXLS.xls";
    generateOutput.displayFromExcel (xlsPath);
}   
}
```

Comment: but `2859.0` is double, what you need to do is remove everything after `.` before you convert number to integer, or convert this to double and round result

Comment: Are you sure that last column is not calculated? If it were calculated by some formula it would fall into `default` case of your switch. Also could you explain what you mean by `it's not parser`? Does `while (rows.hasNext ()) {` loop doesn't reach it or is it ignoring that case?

Comment: None of the columns have formulas. I don't use formulas in excel at all. Moreover, I think it's ignoring it somehow..

Answer (score 0):

I cannot came up what's wrong with the last column but I might explain about the double thing.
Basically if cell type is set as `HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` you can only obtain double representation of whatever it was originally.

Now, each `HSSFCell` has `HSSFCellStyle`-value property (by `getCellStyle()`) which describes its style - here's stored information what is exact format of that number (if its number - actually there is a lot of other information stored here). To find out what was the original format you must call `getDataFormat()` method and compare it to chosen from [BuiltinFormats](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html) - for integer that would be `BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(1)`. If they matches e.g.:

```
BuildInFormats.getBuiltInFormat(1).equals(cellStyle.getDataFormatString());
```

you should be able to safely cast that that `double` to `int` e.g.:

```
if (BuiltinFormats.getBuiltInFormat(1).equals(cellStyle.getDataFormatString())) {
    rowData.add( Integer.toString((int) cell.getNumericCellValue()) );
} else {
    rowData.add( Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()) );
}
```

About that last column thing, I still trying to figure it out. I'll edit post if I come up something.

EDIT: Ok, this is exemplary approach how I dealt with some similar situation.

Assume that your first row contains headers (and none cell here is merged, that screws things up). You could obtain headers and their respective columns:

```
Map<String,Integer> headers = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
for (Cell _cell : row) {
    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) _cell; // iterator returns Cell, we need to cast it manually
    HSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell.getRichStringCellValue ();
    headers.put(richTextString.getString(), cell.getColumnIndex());
}
```

Assuming that for each next row each respective value should be under the same index as header's, we can try to obtain it:

```
for (String headerName : headers.keySet()) {
    int headerIndex = headers.get(headerName);
    HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(headerIndex);

    if (cell != null) {
        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            // handle number
            continue; // move to next header
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            // handle string
            continue; // move to next header
        default:
            // do nothing
        }
    }

    // handle case where either cell is empty or its type is "not supported"
}
```

Now we can combine it all:

```
ArrayList<Map<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

boolean obtainedHeaders = false;
Map<String,Integer> headers = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();

for (Row _row : sheet) {
    HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) _row;

    if (obtainedHeaders) {
        Map<String,String> rowData = new TreeMap<String,String>();
        for (String headerName : headers.keySet()) {
            int headerIndex = headers.get(headerName);
            HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(headerIndex);

            if (cell != null) {
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    if (BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(1).equals(cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString())) {
                        rowData.put(headerName,  Integer.toString((int) cell.getNumericCellValue()) );
                    } else {
                        rowData.put(headerName, Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()) );
                    }
                    continue; // move to next header
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    HSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell.getRichStringCellValue ();
                    rowData.put(headerName, richTextString.getString ());
                    continue;
                default:
                }
            }

            // handle case where wither cell is empty or its type is "not supported"
            rowData.put(headerName, "[it was empty]");
        }
        data.add(rowData);
    } else {
        for (Cell _cell : row) {
            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) _cell;
            HSSFRichTextString richTextString = cell.getRichStringCellValue ();
            headers.put(richTextString.getString(), cell.getColumnIndex());
        }
        obtainedHeaders = true;
    }
}

for (Map<String,String> values : data) {
    Element dataElement = document.createElement("data");
    rootElement.appendChild(dataElement);

    for (String name : headers.keySet()) {
        Element headerElement = document.createElement(name);
        dataElement.appendChild(headerElement);
        headerElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(values.get(name)));
    }
}
```

That should be more or less working. Important notices:

- I use TreeMap to keep headers - as a result data will be sorted by headers. If that's an issue you should change it to some more suitable data structure,
- this is fast drawn raw example. For best you should refactor it, e.g. extract body of `if (obtainedHeader)` and `else` to separate methods. Similarly with `for (String headerName : headers.keySet()) {` body - if extracted you could replace `continue` with `return` and make everything a lot more cleaner.

Basically how you should deal with it depends on what assumptions you make on excel format. Is there a header that can say you which cells are expected to contains some values? should it be dynamically checked or hardcoded? Are empty cells allowed, if so how should they be handled? That that code like a draft that most likely doesn't meet your requirements but show some approach to the problem in general.

Comment: I think the issue is not only the last column. I just figured out the issue is regarding empty cells. Actually what the current algorithm does is; when the cell is blank it creates the tag of that column but writes the value of next cell unfortunately :/ Do you maybe have now an idea what would the modification be?

Comment: Empty cells, huh? As far as I remember iterator just skips over them, so you'd have to either check each time whether something was skipped or obtain position of last filled cell and check each position from `0` to `lastPositon` whether it contains anything and act accordingly... If you are interested in either of those solutions I can add it to the answer.

Comment: I'd like to see your approach if possible. Thank you

Comment: I added some fast example of how would I dealt with it. Say if there's something unclear.

Comment: The code below which you wrote shows errors:
Map<String,Integer> headers = TreeMap<String,Integer>();
for (Cell _cell : row) {
    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) _cell; // iterator returns Cell, we need to cast it manually
    headers.put(cell.getString(), cell.getColumnIndex());
}

Are you sure there are no errors on code?

Comment: Fixed that, try now. It compiles for me: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7aa611fcf1ae88feca2a

Comment: Thank you so much. But still the code has errors when trying to run it..

Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElement(Unknown Source)
 at com.parser.ExcelXMLParser.displayFromExcel(ExcelXMLParser.java:103)
 at com.parser.ExcelXMLParser.main(ExcelXMLParser.java:142)

Comment: I think the problem with your code now is that it creates the tag names in xml with the data of each cell which should not be the case.
It should create the tag and then the data of that particular cell which belongs to the column...

Comment: The problem was with the parsed data were used to create XML document, try now.

Comment: By try now you mean what? Where's the edited last version of code? Moreover, if that's in the Revisions part of the link of gist it still shows the same error...

Comment: Fixed the error. But still it doesn't parse the data correctly. It parses first 8th column then first then the other. It parses in a strange way.

Comment: Fixed also the parsing problem. The problem was the TreeMap. It was sorting the records. I used LinkedHashMap which resulted in correct output. THank you for your help, I appreciate it!.

Comment: No problem, as I said this was just a sketch/draft and you needed to adjust it to your needs.